# Multiplication of two large numbers of strlen 40 each

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_LEN 200

int checkValidInputNum(char*);

int main() {
    
    char first_num[MAX_LEN];
    char second_num[MAX_LEN];
    printf("Please Enter your first number:\n");
    scanf("%s", first_num);
    
    checkValidInputNum(first_num);
    
    
    printf("Please Enter your second number:\n");
    scanf("%s", second_num);
    checkValidInputNum(second_num);
    
    int output_num_len = strlen(first_num) +strlen(second_num);

    int shifting, inputDataRemainder, inputDataQuotient;

    int output_num[output_num_len];
    for (int i = 0; i < output_num_len; i++)
    {
        output_num[i]=0; //Fill output string of output_num_len with zeroes
        //printf("%i", output[i]);
    }
    
    

    for(int i = 0 ; i <strlen(first_num) ; i++)
     {
        for (int j= 0 ; j < strlen(second_num); j++)
         {
            shifting = (strlen(first_num) -1 - i) +(strlen(second_num) -1 - j);
            inputDataRemainder = ((first_num[i]-48) * (second_num[j]-48)) % 10;
            inputDataQuotient = floor((first_num[i]-48) * (second_num[j]-48)/10);

            if (output_num[0+shifting] + inputDataRemainder > 9)
            {
                output_num[1+shifting] += floor((inputDataRemainder + output_num[0+shifting]) / 10);
                output_num[0+shifting] = (output_num[0+shifting] + inputDataRemainder)%10;
                //printf("Check1");
            }
            else
            {
                output_num[0+shifting] += inputDataRemainder;
                //printf("Check2");
            }
            
            if (output_num[1+shifting] + inputDataQuotient > 9)
            {
                output_num[2+shifting] += floor((inputDataQuotient + output_num[1+shifting]) / 10);
                output_num[1+shifting] = (output_num[1+shifting] + inputDataQuotient)%10;
                //printf("Check3");
            }
            else
            {
                output_num[1+shifting] += inputDataQuotient;
                //printf("Check4");
            }
         }
     }

    if (output_num[output_num_len-1] != 0) printf("%i", output_num[output_num_len - 1]);
    
    printf("The answer is:");
    for (int i = output_num_len - 2; i > -1  ; i--)
    {
        printf("%i", output_num[i]);
        
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int checkValidInputNum(char* text)
{
       for(int i = 0 ; i <strlen(text) ; i++)
       {
           if (text[i] < 48 || text[i] > 57)
           {
               printf("Please Enter your input again:\n");
               scanf("%s", text);
               return checkValidInputNum(text);
           }
       }
       return 0;
}
```

I am trying to multiple two large numbers to determine the output. Each number is smaller than 200-digits in length. The output should be a single integer.

Input params:
first_num: 2312730179961343894238242938502761288775
second_num: 8783549656928600320634308588114585640082

Expected output: 20313980378767882242186765287491308230145683219100946334095285964698734616679550
Observed output:
110313971037876788224218676528749130822101456832190100946334095285964698734616679550

I am assuming that my calculation is wrong with output_num buffer string shifting. Could anyone please confirm and help? Is my inputDataRemainder and Quotient are ok?

Comment: Using `floor` for integers doesn't make sense. Let's start from deleting these.

Comment: Simpler example of failing case: input `50 2` output `00` (expected `100`)

Comment: Using `strlen` in a `for` loop test is an unfortunately common beginner's mistake.  Hint:  The string length isn't changing.  Does it really make sense to call `strlen` *every single time you perform the loop test*?  Of course not.  Call `strlen` *once*, before entering the loop.  Isn't that how you'd do it by hand?  Why should your code do more work than it needs to?

Comment: I have the same result after i remove `floor` for integers

Comment: Also, why are you using meaningless constants like `48` and `57`?  Wouldn't your code be clearer if you used `'0'` and `'9'`?  Don't fight the language.

Comment: Note: `int output_num[output_num_len];` too small by 1 for a _string_. Not that code uses `output_num[]` as a _string_, so far.

Comment: This is a fascinating result, though.  Your code is *so close* to working.  Your result is almost correct, except for a few extra inserted digits, always near a 0.  This has got to be a clue.

Comment: @TomKarzes I wouldn't call it a mistake if it works correctly, but yes, you have a valid suggestion for improvement that might make it run faster when the numbers are really big.

Comment: @TomKarzes *why are you using meaningless constants* That's a somewhat disingenuous comment.  They're not meaningless: every programmer knows what they mean.  And the reason Revanth is using them is equally obvious: *every* beginning C programmer uses raw ASCII constants at first, because using character constants instead is, well, not obvious.  It's a refinement which much be learned.  We can teach that lesson gently; there's no reason to scold.

Comment: @user253751 If someone with a stronger understanding of programming would never do it that way, then it is best regarded as a mistake, especially when it incurs a performance penalty.  Anyone with strong programming aptitude understands that you should avoid making your code do more work than necessary.  It's intuitively obvious. I have never made that mistake in my life.  Needlessly calling `strlen` on each loop iteration is the sort of mistake that people look for in code samples from job applicants.

Comment: @SteveSummit Really?  I had to look them up.  Sorry, but I don't have 48 and 57 memorized.  Why should I?  Why would I ever use those numbers?  They're meaningless.  Using hard-wired numbers like that is very bad practice.  I don't think I've ever done it.  The language defines character constants.  Why wouldn't you use them?

Comment: @Tom Karzes I agree that i am still a beginner to your level of programming. Instead of using hard wired numbers i will use character constants for ASCII. I really appreciate these type of conversations. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @TomKarzes regarding your first point, doesn't the compiler optimize it anyways? And if it doesn't, I don't think the loss of readability is enough to compensate for the speed gains.

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine There are several reasons why that thinking is flawed.  First, deliberately putting loop-invariant function calls in a loop under the assumption that the compiler will move them out is reckless at best.  The compiler may not know the string is loop-invariant.  And it certainly won't be moved unless the optimization level is high.  It also makes debugging more difficult, since the more aggressively the optimizer transforms the code, the less relationship it bears to the original source.

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine And finally, it makes the code *less* readable.  When a `strlen` call is seen in a loop test, it is implicit that it is necessary, and that the string (or the pointer) is being modified in the loop.  There is no other good reason for having it there.  At best, you have to look through the loop to convince your self it is in fact loop-invariant.  In contrast, if the call is explicitly made outside the loop, it eliminates all doubt:  The length is stored in a local variable which is clearly loop-invariant.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, I agree that is true, but my argument is from the readability side of things. When I see a `strlen()` function, I don't think about "Is the sizes of the string is going to change?" Instead, I just think that the loop will loop over the string (I'll further look into the code to see what it does). When loops are nested together, it is easier for me to wonder "What string whose size is `aStringSize` again?". But I do think that this is a matter of preference.

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine No, it's not.  You're thinking in terms of a language like Python, where (1) strings are constants (immutable) and (2) the length of a string is stored with the string.  So calling `len(s)` is constant-time regardless of how long the string `s` is.  So in Python, it's not unreasonable to put a `len()` call in a loop test.  None of that applies to C.  For the reasons I gave, it really isn't a matter of preference in C.  A loop that makes a single pass over a string should be O(n).  The idiom that you seem to like is O(n**2).  It's clearly unacceptable.

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine As I said, you only see that sort of mistake made by beginners.  No skilled, experienced C programmer does that.  It's a bad idiom.  If you want to learn to write better code, you should break yourself of the habit.

Comment: @TomKarzes first of all this is not `O(n ** 2)` specifically in this question because `#define MAX_LEN 200`. Second, if the speed matters then go for it. But 90% of the time the speed doesn't matter, and I consider optimizations like this to be premature optimization. And (for me), it sacrifices readability (that is why I call this a matter of preference)

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine As I explained, the explicit `strlen` call makes it less readable, because it is no longer obvious that the length is loop-invariant.  And the loop is O(n**2) where n is the string length.  Sure, it's bounded, but it's always going to be bounded at some level (can a string ever be longer than the size of addressable memory?)  The point is that if the string is 199 characters long, and you have a simple loop that just examines each character, it should be doing 199 loads, not 39601 as you prefer.

Comment: Aside: you can cut down on the work by storing each of the partial products of multipliers `0` to `9`. So if you already encounted a multiplier, you only need to add in the aligned partial product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not checking if `output_num[2+shifting]` exceeds 9 after this line:

```
output_num[2+shifting] += floor((inputDataQuotient + output_num[1+shifting]) / 10);
```

As a simpler example, an input `9909 101` results in an output `9100809` while the correct answer is `1000809`.

This is because the top digit has the value `9` and the second top digit has the value `10`, so they are concatenated and printed as `910`.

To resolve this issue, you shold check if each digits exceeds 9 and deal with carry if yes.

This can be done like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < output_num_len - 1; i++)
{
    if (output_num[i] > 9)
    {
        output_num[i] %= 10;
        output_num[i + 1]++;
    }
}
```

Also note that the line

```c
if (output_num[output_num_len-1] != 0) printf("%i", output_num[output_num_len - 1]);
```

has a wrong position, so the top digit may be printed before the message "The answer is:".

Comment: @RevanthTv I have already wrote a hint about how to fix this. Keep debugging.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, your code works by multiplying each pair of digits and adding them all up with shifting to get a final answer.

E.g. `12 x 45` works by multiplying 1x4 (shift 2), 1x5 (shift 1), 2x4 (shift 1) and 2x5 (shift 0).

The bug seems to be that when you add the shifted numbers into the answer you don't make carries happen more than one digit in the answer. For example, let's say that `inputDataRemainder` is 8 20 times in a row with the same `shifting` (let's say it's 30), and let's look at output_num[32], [31] and [30]. The first time, you add 8 onto output_num[30], so these 3 are 0,0,8. Then you detect adding another 8 would make it bigger than 9, so you carry over onto output_num[31] and now you have 0,1,6. That's correct. But you don't carry over from output_num[31] onto output_num[32], so after adding a whole bunch of 8's, you get 0,10,4 instead of 1,0,4.

In your test you expected to get an output starting with 20313 but you got 110313 instead. That's because it's not 1,1,0,3,1,3 but actually 1,10,3,1,3. The 10 did not carry to the first digit in the output like it should have.

You could fix this by making the carrying into a loop, so it carries as many times as it needs to. You wouldn't need to do the inputDataRemainder and inputDataQuotient separately - you could just treat it all as remainder, then do the carry loop.

Or you can just let the digits get too high, then fix it at the end. You can just ignore the carrying when you add up the shifted numbers, and then before you print the number (or when you print it), you can see if the digit is bigger than 9, and then you take the quotient and remainder and add the quotient onto the next digit, and if *that* digit is bigger than 9 you do the same thing again, etc.